# How do I use JSON in my ActionScript 3?

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash

I have a small Flash game which is written with AS3. My game sends `score` and `game_id`. I have my own encrypt class which calls as `CryptoCode`.

I want to send these variables (`score` and `game_id`) as a JSON object which is encrypted and sent to PHP.

How can I create this JSON object? Can anyone answer me with some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Native JSON API available in Flash Player since version 11 is documented at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS324d8efcab3b0d1e2408f9e3131fddffcfc-8000.html

Basically what you need is to use `JSON.stringify()` method and pass your object as a parameter.

You will get a serialized JSON string in return.